# Is there a way to install self hosted integration run time in linux using shell script?

Tags: azure

I am working in Microsoft Azure. I have created a table in a database in postgres in linux virtual machine(vm) using shell script. Now, I have to move this created table to blob storage.
I come to know that I have to install self hosted integration run time in linux, since my data is in the vm. So is there a way to install and set up integration run time there?

I have one more question.
Since my source is postgres I create a linked service with postgres.
What would be the server name, user name and password? Will it be the vm's  user name and password or the user name and password of database in postgres?

Comment: I downloaded ConfigManager.exe in my windows machine and moved it to the vm.When I executed it using ./ConfigManager.exe ,it says "-bash: ./ConfigManager.exe: Permission denied"

Answer (score 0):

Unless

- The data store is located inside an on-premises network, inside Azure Virtual Network, or inside Amazon Virtual Private Cloud.
- The data store is a managed cloud data service where the access is restricted to IPs whitelisted in the firewall rules.

Then Azure Data factory can connect to Postgre SQL without a need for integration runtime.

And no you can't install this on Linux.

Even if you would manage to do it somehow it wouldn't be recommended as it wasn't built with this in mind.

Comment: So since my data store is located at virtual machine.I will require integration run time.But it can't be installed on linux. So,  is there any way to move the tables in the database in postgres in linux virtual machine to azure?

Comment: Note Integration runtime doesn't have to be on the same machine, you can install it on any windows machine in the same network. Also if that virtual machine is publicly visible (you can connect to it from public internet) you don't need integration runtime at all.

Comment: Please consider marking this as an answer if it helped you.